# Задать значение поля enum не через конструктор, а через property file

Tags: java, spring, enum, properties

Как с помощью `Spring`  можно задать значение поля `enum` не через конструктор, а через `property file`?

Чтобы было не:

```
public enum NetworkName {
    CONTENT_AD("contentad", "Content.Ad");

    private String namePattern;
    private String name;

    NetworkName(String namePattern, String name) {
        this.namePattern = namePattern;
        this.name = name;
   }
}
```

а что-то наподобие:

```
public enum NetworkName {
    CONTENT_AD("contentad");

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    private String namePattern;
    private String name;

    NetworkName(String namePattern) {
        this.namePattern = namePattern;
        this.name = env.getProperty(String.format("network.name.%s", this.name()));;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался все-таки как сделать!

```
public enum NetworkName {
    CONTENT_AD("contentad");

    private String namePattern;
    private String name;

    NetworkName(String namePattern) {
        this.namePattern = namePattern;
        setName();
    }

    private void setName(){
        this.name = getProperties().getString(String.format("network.name.%s", this.toString()));
    }

    private static ResourceBundle properties;

    private static ResourceBundle getProperties() {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("cct-shared");
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```